# Prevent Vuejs application from rewriting URL

Tags: java, vue.js, jboss, single-page-application

I have a Java web application which runs on a JBoss server on: **http://192.168.0.115:8080/war-name-goes-here/**. I'm trying to convert the .jsp pages into a **SPA** using Vuejs, but I notice that when I run the Vuejs application it overwrites the URL and it converts to just: **http://192.168.0.115:8080**. Is this a normal behavior of a Vuejs application run on a Java back-end or should I change any configuration of the server? Thnx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The base URL of the app is `'/'` by default.

So add  `base` option to you router constructor options

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  base: "/war-name-goes-here/",
  routes
})
```

Reference - [Router construction options](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#base)